# Not finding key in local dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, flask

I'm storing key/values in a local dict `EMAIL_INFO` upon a get request and then calling from the dictionary upon a post request. For some reason, when I submit the post, I receive an error that the key I'm looking `"candidate_email"` for is not in my dict. This doesn't make sense to me.

```
@app.route('/candidates/messages/<payload>/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def message_to_candidate(payload):
    EMAIL_INFO = {}
    if request.method == 'GET':
        s = get_serializer()
        try:
            candidate_email, company_email = s.loads(payload)
            EMAIL_INFO['payload'] = get_activation_link(candidate_email, 'introduction', company_email)
            EMAIL_INFO['candidate_email'] = candidate_email
            EMAIL_INFO['company_email'] = company_email 
            EMAIL_INFO['company_link'] = '%s%s' %('www.', company_email.split('@')[1])
        except BadSignature:
            raise   
        return render_template('message_to_candidate.html') 
    else:
        EMAIL_INFO["message_to_candidate"] = request.form["message_to_candidate"]
        send_email(subject="A company has show interest in you...", 
            sender="TalentTracker",   
            recipients=[EMAIL_INFO['candidate_email']],
            html_body = render_template("email_message_to_candidate.html", email_info=EMAIL_INFO))
        return "Email Sent"
```

Comment: The creation of that key is conditional within the first block- so as the dictionary is redefined every call, and accessing that key is in a block that only executes if the first block isn't entered (`else`), that key is never there when you need it.

Comment: A new, empty `EMAIL_INFO` is defined every time that function is called.  The value is not "saved" between calls.  If you want something to be stored across requests, you need to save it somewhere external to the function.

Comment: Thanks! Makes more sense now.